# In Objective-C, why does the compiler care about variables with the same name in two totally different view controller classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I noticed that when I attempt to use the same variable name in different view controllers then the compiler will complain and won't build.  Why does the compiler care about variables with the same name in two totally different view controllers?  What brought me to this question is that I want to pass data from View Controller A to View Controller B in order to avoid making a 2nd network call in my app.

View Controller A:

```
#import "UIKit.h"

@interface MenuController ()<UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate>


@end

@implementation MenuController

NSString *userFirstNameString;
NSString *userLastNameString;

@end
```

View Controller B:

```
#import "UIKit.h"

@interface MenuControllerB ()<UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate>


@end

@implementation MenuControllerB

NSString *userFirstNameString;
NSString *userLastNameString;

@end
```

Screenshot of error:
[image]

Comment: @matt thanks because your question helps me get closer to deciphering if a property or ivar is the "right" choice in Objective-C.  I think what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: Well, I don't see why. Those are _neither_.

Comment: These are global variables; you were likely trying to create local variables or even local properties. Try adding @property infront of the NSString; or after your <delegates> add a { } and move the NSStrings in there.

Comment: With the latter option, are the {} required because I rarely see them in other projects?  With the use of {} does that mean anything specific? @AlbertRenshaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of knowing C. Objective-C is C.

Think about the status (scope) of those NSString declarations. They are not instance properties. They are not locals. What do you suppose they are...?

That's right. They are *globals*. So there is only one namespace, and now you have conflicting global declarations.

To prevent that, declare the strings `static`. That is exactly what `static` is for, at file level: it prevents the declaration from leaking out into the global namespace.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know that I was creating global variables which seems like overkill.  Would you say using class variables is the best approach or would you create either a property or ivar? And thank you by the way!

Comment: The best approach to _what_? Passing variables from one view controller to another? That's what methods are for. Arrange your methods to facilitate your data-passing architecture. Never lazily misuse globals or class variables for this.

Comment: Yes.  I'd like to apply what you're saying because right now I don't see the harm in passing variables to the second view controller if both view controllers set their variables as static.  Would you argue against that process and instead create properties?

Comment: You should never need to use static variables. Or globals.

Comment: Instead of making these static, given where they are, they are probably meant to be instance variables. So make them instance variables by putting them in curly braces: `@implementation SomeClass { // ivars here } // methods here @end`.